# Trying to display the latest sale date while considering existing data

Tags: sql

I have a `customers` and `sales` table, the `account` table contains a `last_sale` column which holds data imported from a previous system I used for Sales. I would like to update this field using the `sales` table which contains all new sales from 2017 onwards.

I have created a query which contains a CASE statement that should compare the greatest date in the `sales` table with the existing data in `customers`, if its greater then it will display the new date, otherwise it should display any existing dates found from the `account` table.

However it appears that my doesn't correctly do this, you can see from my fiddle that it only returns 36 records, even though the original `account` table has 49 records with `last_sale` populated, at the very least there should still be this may rows.

[SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2exG5cdUTEERVCS8GYaiiS/0)

**Query**

```
SELECT c.account_id, 
CASE
    WHEN c.last_sale IS NULL AND MAX(s.sale_date) IS NOT NULL THEN MAX(s.sale_date)
    WHEN MAX(s.sale_date) IS NULL THEN c.last_sale
    WHEN MAX(s.sale_date) IS NOT NULL AND c.last_sale IS NOT NULL AND c.last_sale < s.sale_date THEN s.sale_date
    ELSE c.last_sale
END AS 'sale_date'
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN sales s ON c.account_id = s.account_id
WHERE sale_date <> ''
GROUP BY c.account_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need a `left join` and to fix up some of your logic:

```
SELECT c.account_id, 
       (CASE WHEN c.last_sale IS NULL AND MAX(s.sale_date) IS NOT NULL THEN MAX(s.sale_date)
             WHEN MAX(s.sale_date) IS NULL THEN c.last_sale
             WHEN MAX(s.sale_date) IS NOT NULL AND c.last_sale IS NOT NULL AND c.last_sale < MAX(s.sale_date)
             THEN MAX(s.sale_date)
             ELSE c.last_sale
        END) AS sale_date
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     sales s
     ON c.account_id = s.account_id AND s.sale_date <> ''
GROUP BY c.account_id, c.last_sale;
```

The DB Fiddle for this is [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2exG5cdUTEERVCS8GYaiiS/0#&togetherjs=TDccyN61xa).

I don't follow all the logic in the query, but I wonder if something as simple as:

```
SELECT c.account_id,
       (CASE WHEN MAX(s.sale_date) > c.last_sale
             THEN MAX(s.sale_date) ELSE c.last_sale
        END)
. . .
```

would do the trick.

Comment: Could you try running the suggestions in the fiddle I provided? the first suggestion still only returns 36 records (when there should be at least 49) customers with `sale_date` populated.

Comment: @Imran . . . The first did return 49 or 50 rows when I ran it (which was before I posted the answer).

Comment: I'm not sure we're loading the same fiddle, when I click on https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2exG5cdUTEERVCS8GYaiiS/0#&togetherjs=TDccyN61xa and run the query I get account_id's 15-50 (36 rows in total).

Comment: @Imran . . . Your fiddle does not have the query in this answer.  Somehow, mine doesn't either, but it really does work -- now having run it twice.